# User saved through Wordpress backend does not show up in database table users

Tags: database

I am troubleshooting WordPress installation. When I save the user through the user interface in Wordpress, the newly created user does not show up in the user table in the database. The strange thing is that I can log in with the new user to WordPress backend. 
When I create a user directly in the DB (users + usersmeta), I cannot log into the WordPress. 
Database information in the config.php is correct and I am login into the database I am working on. The one discrepancy I am finding is the table prefix in the config file: 'wp_' in the config and in the database the prefix is different. 
So far I have tried creating new database admin accounts to see if it a matter of user rights. I have contacted hosting provider's staff to check if there are any redirections or other issues. I have also checked the files for other config.php files and also checked other databases on the hosting server.
Did anyone have similar experiences? The website is a few years old. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my findings hoping that someone will find it helpful. After checking the database for the umpteenth time, I have realised, that there have been other installations in the same database. All of them not in use and long forgotten. Everything has been saved in the database in the tables with the correct prefix, there were just so many tables! It was a project for someone else and I simply did not realise in the first place that there were more installations in the same db.

The database was correct and all information found.